# Create two branches under a new project on VSTS

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfvc

I have a brand new project on VSTS which is still empty. I haven't checked in anything yet.

I want to create two branches i.e. **Develop** and **Production**.

How do I do this? I see no options to create branches neither on the portal nor within Visual Studio 2017.

The idea is that I check my project on my local machine into the "Develop" branch and not into the root of the project repository on VSTS.

BTW, I'll be using TFVC for the project.

UPDATE:
Inside Visual Studio, I connected to the project repo on VSTS using Source Control Explorer. I then right clicked the empty repo and clicked to create a new branch but here's the error I got:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create branches from within Visual Studio (or from the command line via [`tf.exe`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-command)). Create your trunk branch by adding a folder and checking it in, then create branches from that. The act of branching from a folder that is not already a branch will turn that folder into a branch.

As an aside: Having a separate "production" branch doesn't serve much purpose in most cases. Create a trunk (the TFVC convention is to call it *Main*), then create a *Development* branch off of it. When code is ready to ship, merge it back to *Main* and build/deploy from there.

Comment: Please see the update I posted to my original post. I tried that but got an error.

Comment: You have to add a folder to the Team Project root first.

Comment: In my source control exlorer, Add Folder is grayed out.. If I check in my ASP.NET project into the empty repo first, I think it'll create a folder and put all my source code in that folder. I should then be able to "convert" that folder to branch. Am  I going in the right direction here?

Comment: You have to map the project root to a workspace before you can interact with it.

Comment: Yes, it all worked now. I really appreciate your help. Maybe it's me but I really find this process to be very unintuitive. Anyway, thanks again.